# Drag and drop events in Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am learning jQuery draggable and droppable UI in that I am facing problem of handling events,

here is the my code

CSS:

```
#draggable 
{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: blue;
}
#droppable 
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 0;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;

}
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="droppable">Drop here
<label id="l1"></label>
</div>
<div id="draggable"><input type="text" style="width: 90px;" id="t1"></div>
```

javascript:

```
var text;
$( "#draggable").draggable({
    revert: true , 

  stop: function(){
      alert("over");

      document.getElementById('t1').value  = "";
  }

});
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function() {
    alert( "dropped" );
    text = document.getElementById('t1').value;
    console.log(text);
    document.getElementById('l1').innerHTML = text;
 }
});
```

Here when draggable div drops, I want to set the text that is in textbox of draggable to label that is in droppable div but some how text is not set.

So please help me with this, I know I have make silly mistake in this but I am able to find it.

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood what you asked correctly but I wish this would help.

You can use `jQuery` throughout if you wish.

`element.val("");`  to set the text of an element.

`text = draggableText.val();` to get the text of an element.

`droppableText.text(text);` to set the text of a label.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5mrz37wn/

CSS:

```
#draggable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

#droppable {
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  top: 0;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="droppable">Drop here
  <label id="l1"></label>
</div>
<div id="draggable">
  <input id="t1" type="text" style="width: 90px;">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var text;
var draggableText = $("#t1");
var droppableText = $("#l1");

$("#draggable").draggable({
  revert: true,
  stop: function() {
    alert("over");
    draggableText.val("");
  }

});
$("#droppable").droppable({
  drop: function() {
    alert("dropped");
    text = draggableText.val();
    console.log(text);
    droppableText.text(text);
  }
});
```

Some references for your `jQuery` study:

> http://api.jquery.com/val/
>
> http://api.jquery.com/text/

You can always refer to these documents to find more about the available methods.

Comment: Your Answer is very helpful to me.When One drag and drop is completed , and when another is started the previous text was removed, If I want that text and another text should be added How to do that?  @Dar

Comment: @RaviVasani Do you aim to (1) add another label to show text or (2) append to the text? The difference between the two is that in (1), you would be creating a new element (new `label`) inside the `droppable` div. In (2), you will just be editing the `text` of the existing `label` inside `droppable` div.

Comment: That was helpful. Thank you @Dar

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can do this with javascript alone.

```js
window.allowDrop = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (ev.target.getAttribute("draggable") == "true")
        ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "none"; // dropping is not allowed
    else
        ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "all"; // drop it like it's hot
};

window.drag = function(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("id", ev.target.id);
};

window.drop = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var id = ev.dataTransfer.getData("id");

    var dragged = document.getElementById(id);
    //dragged
    ev.target.appendChild(dragged);
    c = dragged.childNodes;
    document.getElementById("l1").innerHTML = c[0].value;
};
```

```css
#draggable 
{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: blue;
}
#droppable 
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 0;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;

}
```

```html
   <div id="droppable" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Drop here
<label id="l1"></label>
</div>
<div id="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><input type="text" style="width: 90px;" id="t1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
```

```css
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em;cursor:move; }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


 
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

> More :https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Answer (score 0):

This example may helps you :

```js
function dragStart(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
}

function allowDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

function drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
.droptarget {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<p>Drag and Drop Jquery example</p>

<div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <p ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="dragtarget">Drag me!</p>
</div>
<div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<p id="example"></p>
```